# Importing Android Studio project to Intellij wrong gradle version

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I have a little problem with importing Android Studio Project to Intellij Idea 14.0.2 I'm using wrapper of version of gradle. I'm co-working on a project with my friend but he's working on Android Studio and i prefer Intellij Idea (i know it's propably almost the same, but i don't like having bunch of IDE's doing same job)... Any suggestions? Underneath is log from intellij

```
2014-12-23 13:27:20,243 [  94097]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 
2014-12-23 13:27:20,248 [  94102]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 
2014-12-23 13:27:20,271 [  94125]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Hajto-Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit1.gradle] 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,409 [  99263]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Failed to set up Android modules in project 'LanceIt' 
org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported method: BaseArtifact.getJavaCompileTaskName().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
    at org.gradle.tooling.model.internal.Exceptions.unsupportedMethod(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.getJavaCompileTaskName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.updateGradleTaskNames(AndroidFacet.java:1154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.syncSelectedVariant(AndroidFacet.java:1145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.configureFacet(AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.customizer.android.AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.customizeModule(AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.customizeModule(AndroidProjectDataService.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.access$100(AndroidProjectDataService.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService$1.run(AndroidProjectDataService.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.doImport(AndroidProjectDataService.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.service.AndroidProjectDataService.importData(AndroidProjectDataService.java:97)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask$2$1$1.run(ProjectSetUpTask.java:117)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.mergeRootsChangesDuring(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask$2$1.execute(ProjectSetUpTask.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$6$1.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:374)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil$6.run(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:371)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:391)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:369)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:365)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask$2.run(ProjectSetUpTask.java:109)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$8.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:329)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$9.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:340)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2108)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runWhenProjectIsInitialized(StartupManagerImpl.java:337)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask.populateProject(ProjectSetUpTask.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask.access$000(ProjectSetUpTask.java:46)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask$1.run(ProjectSetUpTask.java:68)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:577)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:384)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2014-12-23 13:27:25,410 [  99264]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2  Build #IU-139.659.2 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,410 [  99264]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - JDK: 1.8.0_25 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,410 [  99264]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,410 [  99264]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,411 [  99265]  ERROR - vice.AndroidProjectDataService - OS: Windows 7 
2014-12-23 13:27:25,766 [  99620]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 21 ms
```

And gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myAppID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile project(':swipeToDismissUndoListmaster')
}
```

And props:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: What does your gradle-wrapper.properties file look like?

Comment: updated post, last code block

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ 14.0.2 uses an old version of the Android gradle tool.

For now you should just revert the gradle tool in build.gradle as such:

Android studio project build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

Your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.4'
}
```

I think I read somewhere that IntelliJ 14.0.3 will have a fix for this.

Comment: I'll check that as soon as i'll be back home.

Answer (score 1):

For others who get this error in Android Studio Beta when trying to build up-to-date Gradle projects from VC, go to help->check for updates again to download the latest available Android Studio Beta version, and your project should build successfully (this may change in the future as even more changes are made to Gradle).

You must [redownload Android Studio entirely](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) since Android Studio Beta does not allow itself to be patched automatically to version 1.0 and onwards.